# DWT in Verilog(FPGA Implementation)

Tags: verilog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DWT in Verilog(FPGA Implementation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282520/dwt-in-verilogfpga-implementation)

Can anyone tell me how to write a verilog code for DWT of an image and dump in to fpga.